# How do we construct the matrix representation for three Grassmann numbers?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fermions, linear-algebra, grassmann-numbers

I want to know how we find or construct the matrix representations for Grassmann numbers.
For example, we can see from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number:
Grassmann numbers can always be represented by matrices. Consider, for example, the Grassmann algebra generated by two Grassmann numbers 1 and 2. These Grassmann numbers can be represented by 4×4 matrices:
$$\theta_1 = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 &
 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\ \end{bmatrix}\qquad \theta_2 =
 \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ 0&-1&0&0\\
 \end{bmatrix}\qquad \theta_1\theta_2 = -\theta_2\theta_1 =
 \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\\ \end{bmatrix}.$$
In general, a Grassmann algebra on $n$ generators can be represented by $2^n \times 2^n$ square matrices. Physically, these matrices can be thought of as raising operators acting on a Hilbert space of n identical fermions in the occupation number basis. Since the occupation number for each fermion is 0 or 1, there are $2^n$ possible basis states.

Does there exist a general method to construct these matrices if one has three or $n$ Grassmann numbers? How to connect the relation between the Grassmann numbers and the Ferminoic path integral on QFT? How to understand that "Physically, these matrices can be thought of as raising operators acting on a Hilbert space of $n$ identical fermions in the occupation number basis. Since the occupation number for each fermion is 0 or 1, there are $2^n$ possible basis states."?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you find a particular representation for Grassmann numbers?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/95259/how-do-you-find-a-particular-representation-for-grassmann-numbers)

Comment: Yeah, I was just typing that. The real question is (IMHO) what are these reps good for? They just get really big for lots of creation/annihilation operators. Their use in path integrals has also been confusing me forever.

Comment: The observation that occupation numbers are 0 or 1 => $2^n$ is correct. Raising/lowering operators and corresponding projectors can be written as 2x2 matrices. In this case, 'high' is fermion, 'low' is vacuum. Quite different things in contrast to spins where 'up' and 'down' are still the same fermion, only reversed. That make the whole thing confusing.

Comment: @expikx I still study it. And I am just wondering that does there exist the other ways to find the matrix representation for Grassmann numbers.