# Meaning of the fermion path integral?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions, integration, grassmann-numbers

I'm trying to understand fermion fields with the Feynman integral. Is there an explicit matrix representation of the Grassmann numbers used in the field integral? Is there a Grassmann-valued measure that results in the Berezin integral? In my book, they just introduce the algebraic relations $ab = -ba$ with no construction of $a$ or $b$, and I'm having trouble visualizing it.

Comment: For matrix representations, see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95259/50583 and its linked questions

Comment: Related: [Basic Grassmann/Berezin Integral Question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/15786/2451)

Answer (score 2):

You are not alone in this. I tend to regard the Grassmann integral as tool for combinatorics, but if you want a deeper view and a discussion of analytic subtleties you might like to read Martin R. Zirnbauer, *Riemannian symmetric superspaces and their origin in random-matrix theory*, J. Math. Phys.\ 37 (1996) 4986;  arXiv:math-ph/9808012.

Answer (score 0):

Grassmann variables are just a convenient way of representing determinants in path integrals. Hence the anti-commutativity. There is some similarity with Slater determinants, which represent fermions in multi-particle quantum mechanics.

What is kind of strange, is that determinants also appear in gauge-fixed path integrals of Yang-Mills fields (i.e. bosons), where they are called Faddeev-Popov determinants and represent ghost fields.

If I remember correctly, the latter appear in the "numerator" of the path integrand, while the "regular" fermion determinants appear in the denominator. Hence they cannot be interpreted as an integral over a hypersurface of the configurations (unlike the gauge-fixed Yang-Mills fields, which **are** integrated over the hypersurface of the configurations that satisfy the chosen gauge condition).