# Matrix representation of Grassmann variables and Berezin Integrals

Tags: representation-theory, fermions, linear-algebra, grassmann-numbers, superalgebra

In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95259/177077) question, the problem of finding matrix representations for a set of Grassmann variables is discussed.

How can this representation be used in Berezin integrals or Grassmann derivatives?
Can one define a Berezin integral as a linear transformation acting on these matrix representations as a superoperator?

For a set of $N$ generators $\theta_n$ and a given representation
\begin{equation}
\theta_n = (\bigotimes_{1}^{n-1} \sigma_z) \otimes \sigma_- \otimes (\bigotimes_{n+1}^{N} 1),
\end{equation}
I  thought of the map
\begin{equation}
\theta_n \rightarrow ((\bigotimes_{1}^n  \sigma_z) \otimes (\bigotimes_{n+1}^N 1)) [\theta_n, (\bigotimes_{1}^{n-1} \sigma_z \otimes \sigma_+ \otimes (\bigotimes_{n+1}^N 1)],
\end{equation}
where the brackets are a commutator, which seems to respect the main features of the Berezin integral of a Grassmann variable $\theta_n$, but I don't know if it satisfies all of them.